# Why getch() is not working in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, getch

Below code works in DevC++ with MinGW works flawlessly but Visual Studio 2008 spits this:

```
error C3861: 'getch': identifier not found .
```

What can I do to accept getch() if this is not possible is there an alternative to getch() that I can use to pause the screen?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){

    char str[] = "This is the end";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    getch();   //I tried getchar() also still does not work
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How about [getc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5231d02a(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: error C2660: 'getc' : function does not take 0 arguments

Comment: You have to pass it the stream you want to read from, in this case `getc(stdin)`.

Comment: I added getc(stdin) but it still does not pause.

Comment: Odd, I run VS2012 and it sure does pause. May be a change in how it works since VS2008 then.

Comment: You are right. My Visual Studio is old I think.

Answer (score 6):

use [_getch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

e.g.

```
#define getch() _getch()
```

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define getch() _getch()
#endif

int main(void){

    char str[] = "This is the end";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which header should I include for it?

Comment: @user1939432 `#include <conio.h>`. `getch()` without an underscore is declared there too, at least in newer versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: @user1939432 `#include <conio.h>` . `#define getch() _getch()` is replacing the convenience.

Comment: I tried it but it gives this error. " error C3861: '_getch': identifier not found" . ıf you have Visual Studio  can you please try if it works or not? If it is working in your machine, I will uninstall Visual Studio. It is such a pain for C

Comment: @user1939432 see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.90%29.aspx work for VS2008, my enviroment VS2010 works.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , what is the _getch() ? Why should we define it?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , is it something defined for C11 compilers?

Comment: @bzal [This POSIX function is deprecated beginning in Visual C++ 2005.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235446(vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @bzal _is it something defined for C11 compilers?_ No. It is not a standard function of C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as well as

```
#include<iostream>

    int main()
{

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```